# What does parseEagerly mean in MTOM's @StreamingAttachment (Metro)

Tags: java, web-services, streaming, jax-ws, mtom

Somebody please explain the behavior of `@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true)`. What are the advantages/disadvantages when its enabled/disabled? Couldn't find any detailed documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Configure such that the whole MIME message is parsed eagerly

- `true` means that the destination should wait until the attachment is fully recieved, and saved to disk, and then it can proceed with the webmethod's business logic.
- `false` means the opposite, so there is no waiting before entering the webmethod itself.

*Feel free to make refinements to this answer.*